Is it legal to park on a single white line at the edge of a road with no pavement?
The AA claims that:

Where the road has a solid, unbroken white line running along the side, parking is considered legal.
In some cases, the single white line is there to indicate that there’s no pavement – if this is the case then it’s illegal to park there.

I can't find anything in the Highway Code corroborating this, though. The sections on parking make no mention of white lines at the edge of the road (or "edge lines" as they're named in the Road markings section later in the Highway Code).
Is the AA correct that (for an ordinary car) parking on a single white line on a road with no pavement is illegal? If so, what law makes this so?

(Illegal? The AA suggests so, but I can't find confirmation. Photo sourced from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzlxoW9QkF0.)

@MichaelHall I linked to that exact page in the question, but (as I noted in the question) I don't see anything pertinent there. Am I failing to spot something?

I doubt you can park if part of the car extends into the roadway, as shown in the picture, that would cause a driving hazard.

@Barmar What's worse is that there seems to be enough space on the side of the road such the entire car could have been parked off the road.

Basically, I don't think you can park on the line. The line separates the road from the shoulder (I wouldn't be surprised if there's a different word in the UK), and you can park on the shoulder. In the US, the shoulder is just for brief stopping, not long-term parking.

With respect to the (universally American) commenters here, you are all making assumptions about how UK roads work that are simply wrong. At least in built-up areas with pavements, parking wholly on the road is not merely legal by default but the norm - hence the need for single or double yellow lines to prohibit it. Parking on grass verges meanwhile is often illegal (dependent on local byelaws), as is parking (wholly or partly) on pavements in both Scotland and London. Most town neighbourhoods have no designated parking. That leaves the road. Parking on roads is simply normal and legal here.

Just an FYI for the Americans in the audience - "pavement" (in British English) means "sidewalk" (in American English), not the road surface you drive on.
